Horizontal split resizing screen dynamic component in angular
I am creating a dynamic component that can contain multiple full-height panel components, where their widths can be resized and adjusted.
For example:

First of all, the container width must always be filled, you can't have free space.
If I want to increase the size of A, it will decrease the size of B accordingly. If B has reached it's minimum width, it will try and resize C, and so on till it can't resize anyone else and the resize function will stop.
This works perfectly fine. However, now I want to do the same for decreasing width.
Let's say I want to decrease the width of B, what happens now is that it will automatically increase the width of C, but what if B has reached it's minimum width? it should try and decrease the previous siblings sizes, so A's width should be decreased accordingly as much as possible.
This creates the effect of pushing panels when resizing.
when I say "decrease B's width", it means increasing C. same as if I want to increase A's width and it will decrease everything else one after another until it cannot resize anymore and reached the max available space.
Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ftujzx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fpages%2Fplatform%2Fhelpers%2Fproject.helper.ts
You can resize by hovering the side borders of every panel
What I did
MouseDown to initialize the resizing:
  @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
  onMouseDown($event: MouseEvent): void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    if (!$event.target) {
      return;
    }

    if (!($event.target instanceof HTMLElement)) {
      return;
    }

    const target = $event.target as HTMLElement;

    if (target.className !== 'split-resize-toggle') { // Todo use the IDynamicHorizontalSplitChild abstraction to get the toggle element to make it dynamic
      return;
    }

    const id = target.id;
    if (!id) {
      return;
    }

    this.currentResizingId = id;
    this.currentResizingElement = this.containerCards.find(card => card.getUniqueId() === id)?.getElement();
    this.startX = $event.pageX;

    this.elementStartWidth = this.currentResizingElement?.clientWidth;
  }

mouseMove handles the resizing:
  @HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove($event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this.currentResizingId || !this.currentResizingElement || !this.startX) {
      return;
    }
    $event.preventDefault();

    const currentWidth = this.currentResizingElement.clientWidth;
    let newWidth = currentWidth + $event.movementX;

    // Get computed styles for the current element
    const currentStyles = window.getComputedStyle(this.currentResizingElement);
    const currentMinWidth = parseFloat(currentStyles.minWidth) || 0;
    const currentMaxWidth = parseFloat(currentStyles.maxWidth) || Infinity;

    // Constrain the new width of the current element
    newWidth = Math.max(currentMinWidth, Math.min(newWidth, currentMaxWidth));

    let widthDelta = newWidth - currentWidth;

    if (widthDelta !== 0) {
      let remainingDelta = this.adjustNextSiblings(this.currentResizingElement, widthDelta);

      // If we couldn't distribute all the delta, adjust the current element's width
      if (remainingDelta !== 0) {
        newWidth = currentWidth + (widthDelta - remainingDelta);
        this.disposeResizeHelperProperties();
      }
    }

    // Update the current element's width
    this.currentResizingElement.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
  }

And the adjustNextSiblings function that tries to resize the next siblings accordingly to fill up the free space.
private adjustNextSiblings(element: HTMLElement, delta: number): number {
    let currentElement = element.nextElementSibling as HTMLElement | null;
    let remainingDelta = delta;

    while (currentElement && remainingDelta !== 0) {
      const currentWidth = currentElement.clientWidth;
      const newWidth = currentWidth - remainingDelta;

      const styles = window.getComputedStyle(currentElement);
      const minWidth = parseFloat(styles.minWidth) || 0;
      const maxWidth = parseFloat(styles.maxWidth) || Infinity;

      const constrainedWidth = Math.max(minWidth, Math.min(newWidth, maxWidth));
      const actualDelta = currentWidth - constrainedWidth;

      currentElement.style.width = `${constrainedWidth}px`;
      remainingDelta -= actualDelta;

      currentElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling as HTMLElement | null;
    }

    return remainingDelta;
  }

The component name is DynamicHorizontalSplitContainerComponent
How can I get the opposite resizing (decreasing width) affect previous siblings + next siblings?
I have a feeling there is a shorter generic way to handle this, but I am over thinking.

I would suggest using a more OOP using this.containerCards, maybe cards could have knowledge of their sibling with each having a linked card left and another right, accessing target with the id like you're doing, and using method on the card object to affect its width. If one is decreasing by its left sibling and reach its minimum, it tries to decrease its own left sibling. If it has none, it returns a significant result meaning "i can't do more' and the original sibling knows it must try decreasing on the other side and stop when no other side can decrease.

Imagine a layout like
<div class="content">
   <div class="left">
      left
    </div>
  <div class="middle">
      middle
  </div>
  <div class="right">
      right
  </div>
</div>

We have a "ruptur" point, the idea is have this two diferent css
  .content{
    display:flex;
    min-height:200px;
    align-items: stretch
  }
  /***when "width" less than "ruptur"**/
  .first{
    width:[width]
   }    
  .second{
    flex-grow:1
  }
  .third{
    width:33%;
  }

  /**when "width" bigger than "ruptur"**/

  .first{
    width:[width]
   }    
  .second{
     width:[min_width_second]
  }
  .third{
    "flex-grow":1
  }

Well, in angular we can use [ngStyle] or [style] to binding to a variable. so we can to have some like
<div class="content">
   <div [style]="styleFirst">
      left
    </div>
  <div [style]="styleMidle">
      middle
  </div>
  <div [style]="styleLast">
      right
  </div>
</div>

And define as variables
  ruptur:number=document.documentElement.clientWidth*.6666-80

  styleFirst:any={width:"33%"};
  styleLast:any={width:"33%"};
  styleMidle:any={"flex-grow":1};

A function that received an object type {width:number}
  changeStyle({width}:{width:number})
  {
    //we check the max_width of the first column
    const maxWidth=document.documentElement.clientWidth-160
    width=(width>maxWidth)?maxWidth:width

    this.styleFirst={width:width+'px'}
    this.styleLast=width<this.ruptur?{width:"33%"}:{"flex-grow":1}
    this.styleMidle=width<this.ruptur?{"flex-grow":1}:{width:'80px'}

  }

makes the trick.
There're severals ways to makes resizable a div, e.g. based in this SO, I create a component that, instead of change the size, only emit an output with width and height
@Component({
  selector: 'split-component',
  standalone:true,
  imports:[NgStyle],
  template: `
    <div #content class="resizable" [class.onDrag]="this.onDrag" [ngStyle]="style" >
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <div #cellTop class="cell-border-top"></div>
      <div #cellBottom class="cell-border-bottom"></div>
      <div #cellLeft class="cell-border-left"></div>
      <div #cellRight class="cell-border-right"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles:[`
   ..omit for abreviate..
  `]
})
export class SplitComponent implements OnInit {
  rect: any;
  incr: number[] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  nativeElement: any;
  typeDrag!: TypeDrag;
  origin: any;
  onDrag: boolean = false;
  moveSubscription: any;
  @ViewChild('content') content!:ElementRef
  @ViewChild('cellTop',{static:true}) cellTop!:ElementRef
  @ViewChild('cellBottom',{static:true})cellBottom!:ElementRef
  @ViewChild('cellLeft',{static:true})cellLeft!:ElementRef
  @ViewChild('cellRight',{static:true})cellRight!:ElementRef

  @Input() set split(value:'left'|'right'|'top'|'bottom')
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{

    this.cellTop.nativeElement.style.display=value=='top'?null:'none'
    this.cellBottom.nativeElement.style.display=value=='bottom'?null:'none'
    this.cellLeft.nativeElement.style.display=value=='left'?null:'none'
    this.cellRight.nativeElement.style.display=value=='right'?null:'none'
  })
}
  @Output() change:EventEmitter<{width:number,height:number}>=new EventEmitter<{width:number,height:number}>()

  classNames = [
    'cell-top',
    'cell-border-top',
    'cell-border-bottom',
    'cell-border-left',
    'cell-border-right',
    'cell-top-right',
    'cell-bottom-right',
    'cell-top-left',
    'cell-bottom-left'
  ];

  style: any = null;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    merge(
    fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'mousedown'),
    fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'touchstart').pipe(map((event:any)=>({
      target:event.target,
      screenX:event.touches[0].screenX,
      screenY:event.touches[0].screenY
    }))
    ))
      .pipe(
        filter((event: any) => {
          const classs = (event.target as any).className;
          if (classs && typeof classs === 'string') {
            const className = classs.split(' ');
            console.log(className.indexOf(classs))
            return this.classNames.indexOf(classs) >= 0;
          }
          return false;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
        this.rect = this.content.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log(typeof(event))
        this.origin =  { x: event.screenX, y: event.screenY };

        this.onDrag = true;
        const className = (event.target as any).className.split(' ');
        this.typeDrag =(this.classNames.indexOf(className[0]) as TypeDrag);

        this.incr =
            this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Top
            ? [1, -1, 0, 0]
            : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Bottom
            ? [0, 1, 0, 0]
            : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Right
            ? [0, 0, 0, 1]
            : this.typeDrag == TypeDrag.Left
            ? [0, 0, 1, -1]
            : [0, 1, 1, -1];

        this.onDrag = true;

        merge(fromEvent(document, 'mouseup'),
              fromEvent(document,'touchend')
        )
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe(() => {
            if (this.moveSubscription) {
              this.moveSubscription.unsubscribe();
              this.moveSubscription = undefined;
              this.onDrag = false;
            }
          });

        if (!this.moveSubscription) {
          this.moveSubscription = merge(
            fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'),
            fromEvent(document, 'touchmove').pipe(map((event:any)=>({
              target:event.target,
              screenX:event.touches[0].screenX,
              screenY:event.touches[0].screenY
            }))
            ))
            .pipe(startWith({ screenY: this.origin.y, screenX: this.origin.x }))
            .subscribe((moveEvent: any) => {
              const incrTop = moveEvent.screenY - this.origin.y;
              const incrLeft = moveEvent.screenX - this.origin.x;
              const width = this.rect.width - this.incr[3] * incrLeft;
              const heigth = this.rect.height - this.incr[1] * incrTop;
              this.change.emit(
              {
                width: (width < 50 ? 50 : width - 1),
                height: (heigth < 75 ? 75 : heigth - 1)
              });
            });
        }
      });
  }
}

Now we can use some like
<div class="content">
  <split-component
    split="right"
    (change)="changeStyle($event)"
    [style]="styleFirst"
  >
    <div class="first">left</div>
  </split-component>
  <div #midle class="second">midle</div>
  <div [style]="styleLast" class="right">right</div>
</div>

You can see the result in this stackblitz
NOTE: I write in styles.css
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

NOTE2: we should recalculate the "ruptur" when window is resized (we can make using rxjs operator fromEvent in the way
fromEvent(window,'resize').pipe(
   startWith(null)
).subscribe(_=>{
   this.ruptur:number=document.documentElement.clientWidth*.6666-80
})


This is a bit different approach and looks like it's built for only 3 panels instead of supporting any number of panels unless i misunderstood. I prefer a non flex solution but I liked the effort, thanks a lot.

Add this function to resize previous siblings when decreasing width:
private adjustPreviousSiblings(element: HTMLElement, delta: number): number {
    let currentElement = element.previousElementSibling as HTMLElement | null;
    let remainingDelta = delta;

    while (currentElement && remainingDelta !== 0) {
        const currentWidth = currentElement.clientWidth;
        const newWidth = currentWidth + remainingDelta;

        const styles = window.getComputedStyle(currentElement);
        const minWidth = parseFloat(styles.minWidth) || 0;
        const maxWidth = parseFloat(styles.maxWidth) || Infinity;

        const constrainedWidth = Math.max(minWidth, Math.min(newWidth, maxWidth));
        const actualDelta = constrainedWidth - currentWidth;

        currentElement.style.width = `${constrainedWidth}px`;
        remainingDelta -= actualDelta;

        currentElement = currentElement.previousElementSibling as HTMLElement | null;
    }

    return remainingDelta;
}

Modify your onMouseMove method to handle both resizing directions:
@HostListener('mousemove', ['$event'])
onMouseMove($event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this.currentResizingId || !this.currentResizingElement || !this.startX) {
        return;
    }
    $event.preventDefault();

    const currentWidth = this.currentResizingElement.clientWidth;
    let newWidth = currentWidth + $event.movementX;

    const currentStyles = window.getComputedStyle(this.currentResizingElement);
    const currentMinWidth = parseFloat(currentStyles.minWidth) || 0;
    const currentMaxWidth = parseFloat(currentStyles.maxWidth) || Infinity;

    newWidth = Math.max(currentMinWidth, Math.min(newWidth, currentMaxWidth));
    let widthDelta = newWidth - currentWidth;

    if (widthDelta !== 0) {
        let remainingDelta = 0;

        if (widthDelta > 0) {
            remainingDelta = this.adjustNextSiblings(this.currentResizingElement, widthDelta);
        } else {
            remainingDelta = this.adjustNextSiblings(this.currentResizingElement, widthDelta);
            if (remainingDelta !== 0) {
                remainingDelta = this.adjustPreviousSiblings(this.currentResizingElement, remainingDelta);
            }
        }

        if (remainingDelta !== 0) {
            newWidth = currentWidth + (widthDelta - remainingDelta);
            this.disposeResizeHelperProperties();
        }
    }

    this.currentResizingElement.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
}


Tried, don't affect at all. I hope this is not a GPT response because I tried all models in many ways and different approaches. Seems like this is too complex or too much context for them
